# How to set hidden window property before the component is loaded?

Tags: authentication, cookies, extjs, hidden

In my application, I have a log in window with two textfields (email and password) and submit button that submits those values to the server:

```
    doLogin: function() {

        var me = this,
            form = me.lookupReference('form');

        me.getView().mask('Authenticating... Please wait...');

        form.submit({
            clientValidation: true,
            url: 'login.php',
            scope: me,
            success: 'onLoginSuccess',
            failure: 'onLoginFailure'
        });
    },
```

I would like have an option ‘remember me on this device’ in login window, so the user doesn’t need to input credentials every time. My idea was to use cookies to store values for email and password.
So, I added a checkbox in login form, and upon successful log in, if checkbox is checked, I save email in cookie:

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set('MyApplication', user_email);
```

And the same I do for the password. Those cookies can be cleared on logout. At the very beginning of the application I can read those cookies

```
Ext.util.Cookies.get('MyApplication');
```

That could be done at the very beginning or for example on ‘beforerenderer’ event of login window.
But now comes the part when I should skip appearance of login window if the user selected that option. Actually, I don’t want to skip that window at all – I would just like to hide it and to maintain its actions.

So, is it possible at some place to add something like

```
if (Ext.util.Cookies.get('MyApplication')){
//    1.    hide the login window so it won't appear at all
//    2.    Set value of email and password textfields to stored values
//    3.    Submit such hidden form to the server
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set hidden in beforerender event and submit the form, in this case user will not see it (it will be rendered in hidden mode):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Form',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,

            // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
            url: 'save-form.php',

            // Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },

            // The fields
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                value: Ext.util.Cookies.get('email'),
                allowBlank: false
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'password',
                name: 'password',
                allowBlank: false,
                inputType: 'password',
                value: Ext.util.Cookies.get('password')
            }],

            // Reset and Submit buttons
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Reset',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Submit',
                formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
                disabled: true,
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            success: function (form, action) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                            },
                            failure: function (form, action) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function(loginWindow) {
                    if(Ext.util.Cookies.get('email') && Ext.util.Cookies.get('password')) {
                        console.log('Hidden');
                        loginWindow.setHidden(true);
                        loginWindow.getForm().submit();
                    }
                }
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arthur. It doesn't work for me. My login form is 'Ext.window.Window' and not 'Ext.form.Panel', so it doesn't recognize loginWindow.getForm(). When I change it to be form instead of window (I am not sure if this is so important), what is missing in your solution is to add success and failure in `loginWindow.getForm().submit(`  However, when I add this I got error [E] No method named "onLoginSuccess" on Ext.form.action.Submit  although I have defined these methods in my controller.

Comment: Because the Ext.form.Basic.submit() does not have onLoginSuccess property in the param object. It has success and failure property functions.. please have a look at the doc: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-submit
To call controller methods from view, you can write something like:  yourWindow.getController().onLoginSuccess()

Comment: Yes, onLoginSuccess is my function defined in controller. Now I can call it using .getController(), but it confuses me why it has to be that way when controller is already defined in view - that's how the same method is called when for example button is clicked.  But now, when use yourWindow.getController().onLoginSuccess() and when I call onLoginSuccess that is defined as `onLoginSuccess: function(form, action) {var user_email = action.result.user_email;}` I got error that form and action are undefined.

Comment: Ok, then refactor the code. I cannot help you without seeing the code.

Comment: Move the beforerender handler from view to your controller and call controller methods from there. Also you can write doLogin method in the controller and move appropriate logic there to avoid DRY.

Comment: How can I center this form on a page?

Comment: try the yourWindow.center() method.